# How to download files using request method to a newly created directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, download

I am using **request method** to download some files. By default, I am able to download the files to the directory where the .py file is there. But I want to change it to some custom path. With below code I am able to create directory as required. But I am not aware how to set the download path to directory I have newly created. Can anyone please help on this?

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
Downloadpath = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H%M")
print("Making directory " + Downloadpath)
os.makedirs(Downloadpath, mode=0o777)
```

Edit: Code to download files is as below

```
 r = https.request('GET', urlname, headers={'Authorization': access_token})

            if r.status != 200:
                return False
            filename = urlname.split('/')[-1]
            filename += '.ext.zip'
            with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
                output_file.write(r.data)
```

Also no. of files is around 200-300. Downloading of files is working fine.

Comment: Please show the code for downloading a file.

Comment: I have added code to download files in the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the filename alone, simply combine it with the path of the generated directory, when writing the downloaded data to a file:

```
os.makedirs(Downloadpath, mode=0o777)

# ...

with open(os.path.join(Downloadpath, filename), 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I am able to download files to the new directory.

Answer (score -2):

```
import os,datetime

currentDir =os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())+"/"+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H%M")
os.mkdir(currentDir)

r = https.request('GET', urlname, headers={'Authorization': access_token})

if r.status != 200:
    return False
filename = urlname.split('/')[-1]
filename += '.ext.zip'
with open((currentDir+'/'+filename), 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.data) 

Above code will work fine for you , 
Only thing you need to do is, just assign the path where **open((currentDir+'/'+filename))**
```